# Desaparecer modal solo al presionar el botón para cerrar en un archivo aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap

Les explico, estoy realizando una ventana modal, es decir, cuando presionen clic en un botón esta ventana se mostrará. Bueno, me funciona correctamente lo que pasa es que dentro de mi modal hay un botón llamado salir para que salga del modal.
Pero cuando yo abro el modal y doy clic en cualquier parte se desaparece lo que yo quisiera que se desaparezca el modal siempre y cuando presionen el botón salir.

Este es mi código actual en Form.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.modal.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery.modal.css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nombre :</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Apellido :</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" runat="server" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Agregar
                        </button>
                </tr>

                <div id="ModalCrear" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">

                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-crear">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                        <span class="hidden-xs">Cerrar</span>
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#Crear', function () {
            $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#agregar_nombres', function () {
            $('#ModalAgregarNombre').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT QUE MUESTRA EL MODAL**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#Crear', function () {
        $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#agregar_nombres', function () {
        $('#ModalAgregarNombre').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para prevenir esto hay dos atributos que debes usar , todo esto especificado en su página oficial [modals-options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options)

- `data-backdrop="static"`  Prevenir el `CLOSE` mediante click fuera de la ventana Modal
- `data-keyboard="false"`  Prevenir el `CLOSE`  mediante Tecla ESC .

Su uso puede ser directamente en HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="ModalCrear" data-backdrop="static" 
  data-keyboard="false">
```

O mediante JavaScript

```
$('#ModalCrear').modal({
   backdrop: 'static',
   keyboard: false
 })
```

**No me fijé que tipo de Plugin se usaba en su código** por eso añadí esta respuesta, pero en realidad la respuesta para el Plugin usado es la de @Roberto León , **estas opciones son para Modal de Bootstrap**

Comment: eso donde se coloca esos codigos ?
me podrias dar un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

El [jquery.modal.js](http://jquerymodal.com/) que usas en el **ejemplo 5** indica como realizarlo:

```
$('#ModalCrear').modal({
  escapeClose: false,
  clickClose: false
});
```

Mira en [Options](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal) donde se dan más detalles.

Comment: Leon Oramas asi:

 $(document).on('click', '#Crear', function () {
            $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
            $('#ModalCrear').modal({
                escapeClose: false,
                clickClose: false
            });
        });

Comment: @Pierro en tu código original cada 'show' reemplazalo por { escapeClose: false, clickClose: false }

Answer (score 0):

Agregando cómo quedaría el código [gracias a la respuesta del buen Dev.Joel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58741/822) Sería del siguiente modo:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#Crear', function () {
        $('#ModalCrear').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
        $('#ModalCrear').modal('show');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#agregar_nombres', function () {
        $('#ModalCrear').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
        $('#ModalAgregarNombre').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

PD: acepta la respuesta de [Dev.Joel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12864/dev-joel), está bien explicada :D